# OCaml functors (parametrized modules) emulation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-families

Is there any recommended way to use typeclasses to emulate OCaml-like parametrized modules?

For an instance, I need the module that implements the complex 
generic computation, that may be parmetrized with different
misc. types, functions, etc. To be more specific, let it be
kMeans implementation that could be parametrized with different
types of values, vector types (list, unboxed vector, vector, tuple, etc),
and distance calculation strategy.

For convenience, to avoid crazy amount of intermediate types, I want to
have this computation polymorphic by DataSet class, that contains all
required interfaces. I also tried to use TypeFamilies to avoid a lot
of typeclass parameters (that cause problems as well):

```
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses
           , TypeFamilies
           , FlexibleContexts
           , FlexibleInstances
           , EmptyDataDecls
           , FunctionalDependencies
           #-}

module Main where

import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

import Distances
-- contains instances for Euclid distance
-- import Distances.Euclid as E
-- contains instances for Kulback-Leibler "distance"
-- import Distances.Kullback as K

class ( Num (Elem c)
     ,  Ord (TLabel c)
     ,  WithDistance (TVect c) (Elem c)
     ,  WithDistance  (TBoxType c) (Elem c)
     ) 
     => DataSet c  where
    type Elem c  ::  *
    type TLabel c ::  *
    type TVect c :: * -> *
    data TDistType  c :: *
    data TObservation c :: *
    data TBoxType c :: * -> *
    observations :: c -> [TObservation c]
    measurements :: TObservation c -> [Elem c]
    label        :: TObservation c -> TLabel c
    distance :: TBoxType c (Elem c) -> TBoxType c (Elem c) -> Elem c
    distance = distance_

instance DataSet () where
  type Elem () = Float
  type TLabel () = Int
  data TObservation () = TObservationUnit [Float]
  data TDistType ()
  type TVect () = V.Vector 
  data TBoxType () v = VectorBox (V.Vector v)
  observations () = replicate 10 (TObservationUnit [0,0,0,0])
  measurements (TObservationUnit xs) = xs
  label (TObservationUnit _) = 111 

kMeans :: ( Floating (Elem c)
          , DataSet c
          ) => c
            -> [TObservation c]
kMeans s = undefined -- here the implementation
  where
    labels = map label (observations s)
    www  = L.map (V.fromList.measurements) (observations s)
    zzz  = L.zipWith distance_ www www
    wtf1 = L.foldl wtf2 0 (observations s)
    wtf2 acc xs = acc + L.sum (measurements xs)
    qq = V.fromList [1,2,3 :: Float]
    l = distance (VectorBox qq) (VectorBox qq)

instance Floating a => WithDistance (TBoxType ()) a where
  distance_ xs ys = undefined

instance Floating a => WithDistance V.Vector a where
  distance_  xs ys = sqrt $ V.sum (V.zipWith (\x y -> (x+y)**2) xs ys)
```

This code somehow compiles and work, but it's pretty ugly and hacky.

The kMeans should be parametrized by value type (number, float point number, anything),
box type (vector,list,unboxed vector, tuple may be) and distance calculation strategy.

There are also types for Observation (that's the type of sample provided by user,
there should be a lot of them, measurements that contained in each observation).

So the problems are:

1) If the function does not contains the parametric types in it's signature,
types will not be deduced

2) Still no idea, how to declare typeclass WithDistance to have different instances
for different distance type (Euclid, Kullback, anything else via phantom types).

Right now WithDistance just polymorphic by box type and value type, so if we need
different strategies, we may only put them in different modules and import the required
module. But this is a hack and non-typed approach, right?

All of this may be done pretty easy in OCaml with is't modules. What the proper approach
to implement such things in Haskell?

Typeclasses with TypeFamilies somehow look similar to parametric modules, but they
work different. I really need something like that.

Comment: I don't know if it would really be recommended, but GHC 7.8 and up allows nullary type classes with the `NullaryTypeClasses` extension. I imagine that this would be orphan instance trouble waiting to happen though.

Comment: How do you plan to use `TBoxType`? You don't have any functions that will return a `TBoxType` in either `WithDistance` or `DataSet`.

Comment: In general, in Haskell, this sort of problem is approached with ordinary old `Data` types and polymorphism instead of type `class`es. This frees you to e.g. easily select the distance function you want by passing it to the function. If type classes are needed and a type could have multiple interpretations, the `instance` is usually selected by using `newtype`s. For example, the `Monoid` class has two obvious implementations for integers, so `newtype`s are introduced to discern between `Sum`s and `Product`s. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Sum

Comment: TBoxType is the same as TVector, just an attempt of alternative approach.

Comment: I found that the talk slides available http://www.stefanwehr.de/publications/WehrChakravarty2008.html to be enough to get the gist of it (but you could also check out Stefan's masters thesis).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is really the case that Haskell lacks useful features found in *ML module systems.
There is ongoing effort to extend Haskell's module system: http://plv.mpi-sws.org/backpack/

But I think you can get a bit further without those ML modules.
Your design follows [God class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) anti-pattern and that is why it is anti-modular.

Type class can be useful only if every type can have no more than a single instance of that class. E.g. `DataSet ()` instance fixes `type TVect () = V.Vector` and you can't easily create similar instance but with `TVect = U.Vector`.

You need to start with implementing `kMeans` function, then generalize it by replacing concrete types with type variables and constraining those type variables with type classes when needed.

Here is little example. At first you have some non-general implementation:

```
kMeans :: Int -> [(Double,Double)] -> [[(Double,Double)]]
kMeans k points = ...
```

Then you generalize it by distance calculation strategy:

```
kMeans
   :: Int
   -> ((Double,Double) -> (Double,Double) -> Double)
   -> [(Double,Double)]
   -> [[(Double,Double)]]
kMeans k distance points = ...
```

Now you can generalize it by type of points, but this requires introducing a class that will capture some properties of points that are used by distance computation e.g. getting list of  coordinates:

```
kMeans
    :: Point p
    => Int -> (p -> p -> Coord p) -> [p]
    -> [[p]]
kMeans k distance points = ...

class Num (Coord p) => Point p where
    type Coord p
    coords :: p -> [Coord p]

euclidianDistance
    :: (Point p, Floating (Coord p))
    => p -> p -> Coord p
euclidianDistance a b
    = sum $ map (**2) $ zipWith (-) (coords a) (coords b)
```

Now you may wish to make it a bit faster by replacing lists with vectors:

```
kMeans
    :: (Point p, DataSet vec p)
    => Int -> (p -> p -> Coord p) -> vec p
    -> [vec p]
kMeans k distance points = ...

class DataSet vec p where
  map :: ...
  foldl' :: ...

instance Unbox p => DataSet U.Vector p where
  map = U.map
  foldl' = U.foldl'
```

And so on.

Suggested approach is to generalize various parts of algorithm and constrain those parts with small loosely coupled type classes (when required).
It is a bad style to collect everything in a single monolithic type class.

Comment: The object with three stuffs - set of observations, distance function and box type is very far from god object.

If your case we'll end up with DataSet class with a bunch of parameters and we'll face the same problem --- types will not be deduced for auxiliary functions that don't accept the dataset but accept only it's parts.

Comment: And also --- vector (the box type) it's an inner detail of implementation of kMeans, the only reason to expose it --- we need the distance function between observations. But different types of containers even don't have common interface for folding, unboxed vectors even don't provide Foldable for them. That's why here WithDistance typeclass.

Comment: But I think the idea of using plain old parametric ADT with newtypes
for specific implementations (Vector, unboxed Vector) is reasonable.

Comment: It's hard to give concrete answer without working code at hand, so I can give only general guidelines. It would be easier if you could provide a bit of working code in OCaml as an example.

Comment: Plain old parametric ADT with all the types and functions collected together will be another example of god object. But as Cirdec suggested in his comment, datatypes are the solution to "named instances" problem, i.e. when you have multiple reasonable instances for a single type.